# prevent the confirm dialog when reload the page

Tags: javascript

[image]prevent the confirm dialog when reload the page using javascript...
bottom of the page there is top page link. 
in the onclick have to reload the page without confirm dialog box. have to avoid that...

```
 function getFormData(dno, rno) {
        var name = document.getElementById("f_nickname").value;
        var digNo = dno;
        var resNo = rno;
        var strVal = digNo + "-" + resNo;
        stp.push(strVal);
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if (!xhr) return false;
             var url = 'ajax.php' + '?prc=' + 'diagnoses' + '&name=' + encodeURI(name) + '&diagres=' + stp;
             alert('zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz');
             xhr.open('POST', url, true);
             xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
             xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                  handle_setVals(xhr);
             };
            xhr.send(null);
            return true;
```

}

```
<form name="mainfrm" id="mainfrm" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="text-align: auto;">
    <input type="hidden" name="f_store" id="f_store" value="" class="w-input">
    <div class="fullpage" id="fullpage">
        <section class="w-section fullsize-page background" id="title-page">
            <div class="title-page-header"></div>
            <div class="title-page-contents">
                <div class="title-container">
                    <div class="w-form">
                            <input class="w-input name-field" id="f_nickname" type="text" placeholder="あなたのお名前" data-name="Name" name="f_nickname" >
                    </div>
                    <a class="w-inline-block play-button" href="#" onClick="playVideo('myVideo1'),getFormData('1','1');"></a>
                    <a class="w-inline-block play-button" href="#" onClick="playVideo('myVideo1'),getFormData('2','1');"></a>
                    <div class="play-button-label">プレイボタンを押してください</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="title-page-footer"></div>
        </section>
      </div>
      <div class="w-clearfix result7-page-message">
              <a class="w-clearfix w-inline-block print-button" href="#" onClick="topPage()"></a>
      </div>
```

```
function topPage() {
        document.getElementById("f_nickname").value = "";
        window.location.reload()
```

};

any idea..?

Comment: What is this for? What are these things? What confirmation dialog?

Comment: Please describe your question clearly ...

Comment: Do you want to repeat the request (make another POST), or just have the equivalent of navigating to the page?

Comment: have to repeat the post.. if just navigate xmlHttpRequest not working...

Comment: sorry for troubling you all. there is a problem in array push... solved...

Answer (score 2):

By disabling this you will expose yourself to re-POST which will mean duplicate information sent to your server. To go to the top of the page scroll there using

`document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;`

Comment: He seems to be using [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/). plugin, so he should be using this instead: `$.fn.fullpage.moveTo(1);`

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to stop the re-POST confirmation is to always redirect from the POST handler (which makes whatever change in state you have to do) to a GET request (that will render the next page, post-change). This way, a refresh will only redo the GET request: no resubmission of POST happens, no confirmation needed.

> have to repeat the post.. if just navigate xmlHttpRequest not working...

This makes no sense to me - there is no reason a xmlHttpRequest would not work intrinsically, so it is something you are doing (or not doing) that prevents it from working.